# synchronized lock on object

Tags: java, methods, synchronization, locking

I am curios about something to do with Java Method Synchronization and Object locking.

When you invoke a synchronized method, from what i understand it locks the entire object for the duration of the method call.

Does this mean you only need to synchronize methods that write data to your object and not for the reading of data from your object?

```
public class testclass {

    private ArrayList<String> data;

    public ArrayList<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public synchronized void setData(ArrayList<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Basically would the above code be thread safe (Since the testclass object is locked while running the setData method)? or should i also synchronize the getData method as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean you only need to synchronize methods that write data to your object and not for the reading of data from your object?

No - if you don't synchronize the reads, you don't have any visibility guarantee (you could get a stale version of the object).

Note: in your case, you don't need to use the synchronized keyword because each method is atomic - you could simply make `data` volatile instead.

Answer (score 2):

locks are not locking object itself, but monitor associated with object. In your case even synchronization of method getData doesn't make testclass thread safe, because it will return instance of "data" field to wild world, and many threads may do whatever they want with object in unpredictable order.

in order to follow "visibility", you either need to make "data" volatile, or synchronize both methods - because JVM is free to optimize bytecode in any way, which makes it possible for some threads to see "stale" data.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't `synchronize`  `getData()` method what guarantee do you have that when one thread first invokes `getData()` first and another thread wants to execute `writeData()` method, the thread is not locked. Hence not thread safe.

[EDIT]
And as other specified, it is not thread safe for you to return the non-volatile Data object too, which might be modified in a non-thread-safe-way outside this class